# JBOSS 7.1 deployment order

Tags: jboss, war

I have a jboss 7.1 in domain mode.

I have many server-group.
It is possible to deploy the war of all server-group sequentially and not parallel?

Order is not important, as long as it is sequential: one by one.

Comment: Is it important to deploy war files sequentially or you just want to get rid of downtime during deployment?

Comment: We have found that if jboss starts normally, it often fails on some packages (to many open file, or similar). We are investigating to understand why.
In the meantime, however, we have experienced that if we restart the jboss with all the war disabled and after the start we start them one by one, regardless of the order, all the packages are deployed correctly.
So I would like to be able to restart in a "controlled" way without having to manually start the packages one by one.